# how to launch a agent from demon in mac

Tags: xcode, macos, plist

I have a bit complicated scenario like below.

1. Agent A is running, which is launched by "launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgent/com.A.test.plist"
2. This Agent launch a installer with command line "installer -pkg /abcd.pkg -target /", this installer run with authorisation
3. In this installer I am running a sh script which run an utility exe,
4. This utility exe has following code
   `        int ret = setuid(uid);

   ```
   int status = 0;
   if ((status = system("launchctl load  -w /Library/LaunchAgents/com.abcd.xyz.plist"))) {
       print error;
       return 1;
   }`
   ```

the above gives error "Operation not permitted"

The same code runs fine if I lunch the pkg by double clicking on it.

regards,
Birajendu

Comment: Check if you have proper permissions.

Comment: The same piece of code works fine in 10.9, but not in 10.11